# Parsing a delimited message (event message from IBM MQ) received in Azure Event hub

Tags: ibm-mq, text-parsing, azure-eventhub, azure-databricks

I have events being received in Azure Event Hub which are in the Format of IBM MQ Text. Source is Mainframe Oracle tables so data is being routed through Oracle Golden Date on the IBM MQ and arrives in Event Hub. 
I am interested in the body of the message which has an Event Name followed by Delimiter and also Tags which are followed by delimited data. There are no column names associated with the data in the message. The idea is to be able parse, map  and further transform this data and  make it available to other applications.
The problem is  how to Parse the Body of the event message which has delimited text and map it to a fixed schema using Azure Data Bricks or Stream Analytics.
Is it only possible by creating a custom parser in Python or Java or another coding language?

Here is the body of a sample message -

```
{"GDSFE001\u00031\u0003N\u00030\u0003Confirm_Shipment_Closed\u00035572214\u0003B\u0003I7EPM0XV1Z8KB\u0003TAG0000\u0001\u000220190516\u00011409\u0001GCSS\u0001Message Broker\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001O\u0001\u0001\u0001N\u0001BKG\u0001\u0001\u0001\u000163.0\u0002TAGT100\u0001HDZKG4XV1Z9KB\u0001BNILG4XV1Z9KB\u0001\u0001\u0001N\u0001N\u00010\u0001Y\u0001N\u00010\u00010\u0001SGPPM0XV1Z8KB\u0002TAG0100\u0001I7EPM0XV1Z8KB\u0001\u0001\u0001O\u0001\u0001\u00011\u0001Order Handling\u00011\u0001Active\u00013\u0001Ordinary Transport Order\u00012019-05-16 13.49.24.683955\u0001NayanKumar\u00012019-05-16 14.09.32.539936\u0001NayanKumar\u00012019-05-16 14.09.32.539936\u0001NayanKumar\u00011\u0001MSL\u00012019-05-16 13.49.24.683955\u0001NayanKumar\u00012019-05-16 14.09.32.539936\u0001NayanKumar\u0001\u0001Y\u0001N\u00011\u0001Booking Confirmation\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u00012019-05-16 13.49.24.683955\u0001NayanKumar\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001A1\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001T2\u00015\u0001GCSS\u00011\u0001CY\u00011\u0001CY\u0001\u0001\u0001\u00014\u0001Telephone\u0001\u00012019-05-09\u0001\u0001\u0001\u000110\u0001Transdoc Invoicing\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001Y\u00012019-05-16 13.49.24.683955\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001N\u0001\u0001\u0001Y\u0001SGPPM0XV1Z8KB\u0001\u00012019-05-09 21.00.00.000000\u0001T2\u0001233\u0001North Europe - United States\u0001MAEU\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001N\u0001Y\u00012019-05-16 13.49.24.683955\u00011\u0001Fixed Date\u00016\u0001Failed\u0001W\u0001N\u0001Y\u0001N\u0001Y\u0001N\u0002TAG0110\u0001J20PM0XV1Z8KB\u0001\u0001\u0001O\u00011\u0001Booking Management\u00012019-05-16 13.49.24.683955\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u00012019-05-16 13.49.24.683955\u0001NayanKumar\u00012019-05-16 13.54.16.577754\u0001AUTOUSER\u000112084\u0001Export Order Handling\u0001AUTOUSER\u0001AUTOUSER\u00011021\u0001AP Moller Copenhagen (MSL)\u0001panama_kvinder@hotmail.com\u0001DKCPHMSL1\u00013D9XA9RMF1PJ2\u0001DK\u0001Denmark\u0002TAG0120\u0001OKZHN0XV1Z8KB\u0001\u0001\u0001O\u00015HKDN0XV1Z8KB\u0001\u0001\u0001\u00010\u00011\u0001Booking Number\u0001\u0001\u0001510185665\u00012019-05-16 13.49.24.683955\u0001NayanKumar\u00012019-05-16 13.49.24.683955\u0001NayanKumar\u0001SGPPM0XV1Z8KB\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001101\u0001Shipment\u0002TAG0120\u0001D8BMG4XV1Z9KB\u0001\u0001\u0001O\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0001\u00010\u00015\u0001Transport Document Number\u0001\u0001\u0001510185665\u00012019-05-16 13.51.42.301735\u0001NayanKumar\u00012019-05-16 13.51.42.301735\u0001NayanKumar\u0001\u0001\u0001BNILG4XV1Z9KB\u0001\u0001151\u0001Transport_Doc
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to update the question with a sample message that you are talking about.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Roger, updated with a sample message

Comment: I have no idea what kind of data format that is, so you should ask the application team who's application is generating the data to provide you with the documentation for the data.  Note: I can see that it is using \u0003 as a delimiter between data fields.  I also see lots of \u0001 and \u0002 characters which are most likely delimiters too.

Comment: In Stream Analytics, you can implement your deserializer in C# which will allow you to read incoming events in any format. You can try this out today by signing up for the preview at https://aka.ms/asapreview1